# How to prevent infinite loop caused by onAuthStateChanged Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a provider component that sets the initial auth context from firebase-auth.

Everything works fine until I try to add persistence in the form of setting up an observer with `onAuthStateChanged`. This checks for auth and I update my state via dispatch method.

But this is causing an infinite loop. I added an unsubscribe function call, but this makes no difference,

Can anyone advise? thanks

```
AuthContext.js

import React from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
//firebaseauth reducer
import { firebaseAuth } from "../reducers/AuthReducer";

export const Auth = React.createContext();

const initialState = { user: {} };


export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(firebaseAuth, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };

  const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "HYDRATE_AUTH",
      payload: user,
    });
  });
  unsubscribe();

  return <Auth.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</Auth.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, have you found the problem?

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is:

1. The component renders
2. It sets the auth listener
3. The listener fires and sets the state of the component
4. State update causes the component to rerender
5. The component adds another listener and everything repeats

Unsubscribing doesn't help because the component keeps rerendering and adding a new listener every time.

We can tell the component to set the listener only once by using `useEffect()`:

```
AuthContext.js

import React from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
//firebaseauth reducer
import { firebaseAuth } from "../reducers/AuthReducer";

export const Auth = React.createContext();

const initialState = { user: {} };


export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(firebaseAuth, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "HYDRATE_AUTH",
        payload: user,
      });
    });
  }, []);
   

  return <Auth.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</Auth.Provider>;
};
```

By providing an empty dependency array to `useEffect()`, we tell it to run the callback only once, when the component initially renders, so the auth listener is set only once.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tomek-ch -- an alternate solution would be to prevent the re-render by storing the state (eg: keep the user bits in the component state) and then do not update the state if its already there (or the same).

In my case I just keep the user the first time, set a boolean state flag, and ignore subsequent events.